# Pound sign displaying problem in outlook in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, outlook, selectedindexchanged

I want to show some amount in outlook with £ sign on selectindexchanged even of a dropdownlist client side.

Amount is displaying with sign in Win XP IE 7,8 but not in Windows 7 IE as given below:

[image]

**HTML:**

```
if($(this[this.selectedIndex]).val() == "A")
{
    var mailsubject="New win";
    var toEmail="abc@sify.com";
    var vSign = "Amount: £" + $(this).parent().siblings()[4].nextSibling.all[0].value;
    var mailbody = escape(vSign); 
    window.open("mailto:"+ toEmail + "?subject=" + mailsubject + "&body=" + mailbody);
}
```

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: How about sending the e-mail server-side? This way, you can set the `SubjectEncoding` to e.g. UTF-8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we got the solution.

we have to enable checkbox for "Enable UTF-8 support for mail to:protocol" 
in

Outlook --> Tools --> Options --> Mail Format --> International Options --> 
Internet Protocols

Comment: yeah if we do this server-side then we can set SubjectEncoding to UTF-8 but in my case this is client side.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the pound sign with its HTML entity:

```
&pound;
```

And don't you mean **JavaScript** / **jQuery**, and not **ASPX**?

Comment: Maybe `%c2%a3` would work? This is the url-encoded pound sign, so if that won't work, I don't know what will...